# How to configure systemctl service for docker installed from binaries?

Tags: linux, docker, opensuse, systemctl, sles

I installed docker from binaries on SLES 15 x86_64 (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/#install-static-binaries). And now I need to configure boot on start up and rootless launch. But I have no docker.service. And I don't understand how to configure it manually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I'd suggest to enable `Container Module 12 x86_64` (aka `sle-module-containers/12/x86_64`) as described [here](https://documentation.suse.com/zh-tw/sles/15-GA/html/SLES-all/cha-docker-installation.html) but I think you have your reasons for not using it.

You need to create the `docker.service` and `docker.socket` files in the `/etc/systemd/system` folder as described in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#manually-create-the-systemd-unit-files).

`docker.service` content can found [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/init/systemd/docker.service) and it's currently:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service containerd.service
Wants=network-online.target containerd.service
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutStartSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

# Note that StartLimit* options were moved from "Service" to "Unit" in systemd 229.
# Both the old, and new location are accepted by systemd 229 and up, so using the old location
# to make them work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitBurst=3

# Note that StartLimitInterval was renamed to StartLimitIntervalSec in systemd 230.
# Both the old, and new name are accepted by systemd 230 and up, so using the old name to make
# this option work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitInterval=60s

# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity

# Comment TasksMax if your systemd version does not support it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this option.
TasksMax=infinity

# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes

# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process
OOMScoreAdjust=-500

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`docker.socket` can be found [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/init/systemd/docker.socket) and it's currently:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API

[Socket]
# If /var/run is not implemented as a symlink to /run, you may need to
# specify ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock instead.
ListenStream=/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```